# How do I set a DefaultValue of a list property?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Helper class as such:

```
class Helper : Settings
{
    [Setting, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool DeclineData { get; set; }

    // ....

    [Setting, DefaultValue(new List<string>())]
    public List<string> AcceptList { get; set; }
}
```

However my `DefaultValue` for `List<string>` results in error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

I've also tried `typeof(List<string>)` which also failed.

`Setting` is actually `System.Attribute` as `Settings` inherits from it, that's not my call as its not my code or open to changes.

My question is, **how can I set a `DefaultValue` to my property `AcceptList`?**

---

While Selman22 answer does not generate a direct error to set the default value, it doesn't let it serialize or deserialize the data and since I am very limited in the information about this obfuscatated API I followed a different route.

This is not a direct solution but rather an workaround until I figure out more information about this API, by setting my `DefaultValue("")` to empty and using my property as string with a delimiter to convert back and forth from a string to a list within a private property I was able to save the data I needed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it has to be a compile time constant, you can only set it to *null*:

```
[Setting, DefaultValue(default(List<string>)]
public List<string> AcceptList { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is the **correct** answer and from my experiment right now, it looks like the only choice.

Comment: As it initializes the property to null it's pointless to use it at all because it'd be null anyway.

Comment: True, but if you look at the question generically (or see it as what options do I have when one runs into that compile error) this is the correct answer. If people google for the error in the OPs post, this answer will give the the right info IMO.

Comment: @Selman22 I get `Setting AcceptList has invalid value "System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[System.String]"!` and it saves it as `<AcceptList>System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[System.String]</AcceptList>`

Comment: @Guapo thats probably because null isn't what it is supposed to be. like I posted in the other comment. Your problem **now** isn't what you've described in your question. Your statement now is: **how do I set a property value it gets serialized**

Comment: With C# 6 do something like this. Public List<string> NewList { get; set; } = new List<string>();

Answer (score 1):

You can set default values of the properties in the constructor.

```
class Helper : Settings
{
    public Helper()
    {
       DeclineData = false;
       AcceptList = new List<string>();
    }
    public bool DeclineData { get; set; }
    public List<string> AcceptList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No, I can't set it that way or the serialization which is also inherited from Settings, will not save the settings.

Comment: You did not mention anything about serialization in your question. Can you elaborate on why it wouldn't work?

Comment: I would love to but the code is not open to me I can see very few of the code using VS and the rest is encrypted/protected as gibberish. It is an application with a very limited API with barely any documentation.

Comment: while selman22 has given you the correct answer the question you've posed, you have a larger problem at hand now. You should probably post **a new question** about **how to assign a specific value to a property before it is serialized**. Remember to include all relevant information.

Comment: @gideon I am lost myself this application have a very limited and not well documented API and honestly I was a loss trying to figure it out.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about your difficulty (and my god I sound like tech support! :/), but now your only solution is to find out how to setup some kind of pre serialization hook to set a value before it goes into serialization. Googling will help of course, do some research and if and when you hit a wall post a new question as I suggested. Currently as it stands **selman22 has answered this question**.